# Add push notifications to an MFC project packaged with the desktop-bridge

Tags: visual-c++, uwp, push-notification, mfc, desktop-bridge

I have a traditional Win32 desktop app written in C++/MFC that I have packaged as a UWP app for the Microsoft store using the desktop-bridge facility in Visual Studio 2019. The VS solution thus contains 2 relevant projects - the main program, which is a standard MFC desktop program, and the Package project. The bundle produced by the packager works and is currently published on the store.

For the next update I would like to enable the user to receive notification messages (toast?) that I send from the Microsoft Partner Center. I want to notify users when another update is available, and also when new data files are available (from my website) for use within the program.

I have read a lot of MS documentation about how to code for push notifications, but it all seem to refer to native UWP applications. I have come across [this](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/02/01/adding-uwp-features-existing-pc-software/) blog which contains a working sample of an MFC program receiving notifications, but to be honest it does not really explain *how* it works, nor does it explain how to retrofit the facility to an existing program.

Can anyone explain (or point to a resource/sample explaining) how to add this facility to an existing MFC program such as mine?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Configure your app for targeted push notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/configure-your-app-to-receive-dev-center-notifications) has a bit more information on the topic. From reading it it seems that this features is deeply entangled with the UWP application model, starting from the fact that the Microsoft Store Services SDK is available for the UWP only. In theory it *might* be possible to re-implement this feature in a classic desktop application, though it won't be as simple as providing application identity.

Comment: Thanks for passing this on. I actually did try to follow the instructions in the link, but couldn't get past the first stage of getting the Store Services SDK recognized in Visual Studio. Probably because I'm not running a UWP project.